# Access POST data outside of post() in Django 1.5 TemplateView

Tags: python, django, post

I am new to Django (1.5) and I am trying to do a basic POST form. I have a `TemplateView` that implements the form (passed to the template using `get_context_data`).

When the form fails for some reason (*e.g.* validation error), I want to show the form again, containing the data that the user has filled. When it succeeds, I want to redirect to a success page (*e.g.* the just-created item).

Here's what I've done so far:

```
class WriteForm(forms.Form):
    subject = forms.CharField()
    text = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
    # some other stuff

class WriteView(MailboxView):
    # MailboxView extends TemplateView and defines some context
    template_name = 'messages/write.html'
    form_data = None

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # treat form data...
        # lets make things simple and just assume the form fails
        # I want to do something like that:
        self.form_data = request.POST
        # should I return something?

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(WriteView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.form_data is None:
            context['form'] = WriteForm()
        else:
            context['form'] = WriteForm(self.form_data)
        return context
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: if you are new to Django I suggest not using class-based views straight away before you feel comfortable using simple view functions. What you're asking for is pretty standard so looking at the simple examples of using forms should be enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django already has a [`FormView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#formview) that you might be able to use. If you want to see how it works, here's the [code on GitHub](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#formview).

If you want to write your own view instead of using the built in form view, you might also find it useful to look at the [`FormView`](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-vanilla-views/blob/master/vanilla/views.py#L76) in Django Vanilla Views, which has a simpler implementation.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm browsing these pages and I will come back and accept your answer when I can make it work :)